# How to validate empty value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is html code for text field what to check for *empty/null* values

```js
function myFormValidation() {
  alert("HI");

  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  alert(name);
  if (name == null || name == " ") {

    document.getElementById("inp1").innerHTML = "Enter your name please";

  } else {
    document.myForm.submit();
  }

}
```

```html
Name
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<input type="hidden" name="inp1" />
<input type="button" value="Register" onclick=" myFormValidation()" />
```

I want to validate using `innerHtml`, but my js is not getting called.

Comment: Add the id `name` to your text field. `e<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />`

Comment: There's nothing causing the event handler not being called. Please post the real code you have.

Comment: It is getting called. First of all you need to assign ID to element with name inp1. Another thing it is of type `hidden` so even if you assign innerHTML; it wont be visible. Also check should be performed name =="" Currently it is checking if it is with space

Comment: @pratikwebdev OP clearly states "My js is not getting called" ...

Comment: Do you have any console errors? Is the js function registered before it is called?

Comment: @Teemu Yes that was before with code error that alert statement was not triggering which Amir pointed out. Even after that code had issues mentioned in my comment. I am not sure how OP was sure that it was not getting called. I believe based on if error message was getting displayed or not. hence pointed out issues.

Comment: I am able to call my js now but not able to print the inner html msg

Comment: @Rahmath `input`s don't have `innerHTML`, they have `value`. And as others have already stated, even having a value, you couldn't see a hidden input on a page.

Comment: @Rahmath As Teemu mentioned above that is one more thing to correct in code. What you could do is change your inp1 from type input hidden to <p> i.e. <p id="inp1" name="inp1"/> This should do the trick for you including above suggested changes. Also you would need to clear content from P if page is being refreshed.

Comment: ... + `#inp1` will need an id too. Also, the value of text input is never `null`, it can be an empty string (what a space is not). Use `if (!name.trim())` to check an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess removing the space between " " may work

your code

```
if(name==null || name ==" " ){

        document.getElementById("inp1").innerHTML = "Enter your name please";

    }
```

change to

```
if(name==null || name =="" ){

        document.getElementById("inp1").innerHTML = "Enter your name please";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like to validate the input edit through the help of regular expressions

```
if ( name == null || /\s*/g.test(name) )
{
    document.getElementById("inp1").innerHTML = "Enter your name please";
}
```

The expression \s* covers both the empty string as well as the input consists of multiple blank spaces, such as "    " for example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with JavaScript/jQuery but I think this is what you're looking for. I've changed your `input` for the message to `label` because your `type` is `hidden` which also means that users will not be able to see the message at all.

Also, you didn't include the `id` attribute for your `inp1` so it's impossible to use `getElementbyId()`.

```js
function myFormValidation() {
    if (document.getElementById("name").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("inp1").innerHTML = "Enter your name please";
    }

    else {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        alert("HI");
        alert(name);
        document.myForm.submit();
    }
}
```

```html
Name:
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<input type="button" value="Register" onclick=" myFormValidation()" />
<label id="inp1"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example:

```js
function myFormValidation() {
  var user = document.getElementById("name").value;
  if (user === "") {
    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "Enter your name please";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = user + " " + "How are you..!";
  }
}
```

```html
Name
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<input type="hidden" />
<input type="button" value="Register" onclick=" myFormValidation()" />
<div id="body"></div>
```